# Python 3.9 can't find tensorflow.keras and subpackages

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, python-3.9

I'm using a conda environment with python 3.9, using `pup install -r requirements.txt` for the packages. I have `tensorflow==2.12` installed, and have tried both with and without `keras==2.12`. Either way, I am getting errors in the IDE (PyCharm) and when trying to run code that indicate it can't find the `tensorflow.keras` package or any of its subpackages, even though I've checked the API reference for the things I'm trying to import.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. (The older questions that I've found by searching all refer to earlier versions of tensorflow.)